# Convert Modified Julian Date to UTC Date in Excel

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula

I am looking for a formula where I can put a 5 digit Modified Julian Date and have it convert it to today's date for me.

I did it in a way where I have a separate sheet with a table but although it works, I am looking for a way without the need of a separate table. Here is some information:

00000 should translate to 11-17-1858

58890 should translate to 02-11-2020

Every time the number goes up 1, it should go up 1 day. This needs to have leap years in consideration as well. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is a website that currently does the conversions:

http://www.csgnetwork.com/julianmodifdateconv.html

This has to be done without macros, literally need it in formula format.

Comment: Note that Excel dates start in 1900 - so anything before that will have to be formatted text and won't be recognized as a date.

Comment: @BigBen I didn't know that so that is good information. I guess it can start from 1900 then, 15020 translates to 01-01-1900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subtract `15018` and format the result as a date.

Why `15018` and not `15020`?

- In Excel, `1-Jan-1900` value is `1`
- In your date scheme `15020` = `1-Jan-1900`
   But, if you had the number `15020` to convert and subtracted `15020` it would --> `0`, not the desired `1`.
- Therefore we reduce the `15020` by `1` to `15019`.

Next, there is a deliberate "bug" in Excel, widely discussed both on SO and the internet, whereby the year 1900 is erroneously classified as a leap year.

So for any date equivalent that is after `28-Feb-1900`, we have to subtract an extra `1`.

*If you might be dealing with dates between `1/1/1900` and `2/28/1900` you will need to modify the formula to take that into account.*

Comment: Genius! Worked like a charm!